# Dialog disappears even if the flag FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED is set, when the screen is locked

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, keyguard

I work on an app and I face a strange issue. When the screen is locked, I have a dialog that appears when the app gets activated and it is working fine for Lolipop, KitKat and older versions. The problem seems to appear only in V6 Marshmallow: the dialog appears for a second and then it seems to disappear in the background. However, if you press where the dialog was supposed to be, the activities of the dialog work as the dialog was really there! I found a lot of answers regarding this issue but none of them seems to work for me. 
In the onCreate() I have set the nessecary flags:

```
// allow to be shown when screen is locked
        Window win = getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
        // winParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        // winParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
        winParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED;
        // winParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
        win.setAttributes(winParams);
```

I've tried also to disable the keyguard with no result:

```
KeyguardManager myKeyGuard = (KeyguardManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock myLock = myKeyGuard.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        myLock.disableKeyguard();
```

This is my declaration in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
            android:name="Activity"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

I noticed that if I remove the Dialog style from the theme, it works. But I need it to be a dialog!

Please have in mind that this code works in all version but V6! Any idea?